# Add an object inside an array of nested object depending of an id existing on the array of the nested object and ignore duplicate

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two Array of objects, the first one and the parent one is "factory".
The FactoryParent array contains objects and inside that list of object there's a list of products,
The second one is an array of products.

First of all I need to detect the factory with a the field `name` and `parent`, after that I need to check my array of products and depending of the field `family.name` and `family.parent` add that particular product to the array of products on the FactoryParent array, if the object exist I need to ignore and goes on until I go through all the array of products ArrayOfProducts

There's an unique UID, if it exists on Factory-->Object--->products[] ignore and check the other one,

```
     FactoryParent = [
        {
            "name": "MT",
            "parent": null,
            "Normes": [
                "NF EN 1111"
            ],
            "version_schema": null
        },
        {
            "name": "MS150",
            "parent": "MR",
            "Normes": [
                "NF EN 7777"
            ],
            "products": [
                {
                    "Id": "78789789784dsz654z",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "MS150",
                        "parent": "MR",
                        "gamme": "RAL X",
                        "serie": "something"
                    }
                }
            ]
    
            },
            {
                "name": "ME150",
                "parent": "MM",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "Id": "45d456d44567a8a798a79a87456",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "Lunatic S",
                            "serie": "something"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e53e",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "MOMS S",
                            "serie": "somting"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "46f654df564df5645646z",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "RAL S",
                            "serie": "somting"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    
     ArrayOfProducts = [
            {
                "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e4974e",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                    "serie": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "sd798d7s8ds756sd4789",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                    "serie": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "46f654df564df5645646z",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "RAL S",
                    "serie": "somting"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "88ds456sd4897sd89d7s",
                "family": {
                    "name": "MS150",
                    "parent": "MR",
                    "gamme": "RAL S",
                    "serie": "somting"
                }
            }
        ]
```

My final array should look like this:

```
finalArray = [
    {
        "name": "MT",
        "parent": null,
        "Normes": [
            "NF EN 1111"
        ],
        "version_schema": null
    },
    {
        "name": "MS150",
        "parent": "MR",
        "Normes": [
            "NF EN 7777"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "Id": "78789789784dsz654z",
                "family": {
                    "name": "MS150",
                    "parent": "MR",
                    "gamme": "RAL X",
                    "serie": "something"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "88ds456sd4897sd89d7s",
                "family": {
                    "name": "MS150",
                    "parent": "MR",
                    "gamme": "RAL S",
                    "serie": "somting"
                }
            }
        ]

        },
        {
            "name": "ME150",
            "parent": "MM",
            "products": [
                {
                    "Id": "45d456d44567a8a798a79a87456",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "ME150",
                        "parent": "MM",
                        "gamme": "Lunatic S",
                        "serie": "something"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e53e",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "ME150",
                        "parent": "MM",
                        "gamme": "MOMS S",
                        "serie": "somting"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "46f654df564df5645646z",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "ME150",
                        "parent": "MM",
                        "gamme": "RAL S",
                        "serie": "somting"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e4974e",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "ME150",
                        "parent": "MM",
                        "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                        "serie": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "sd798d7s8ds756sd4789",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "ME150",
                        "parent": "MM",
                        "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                        "serie": null
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Edit : What I have done :

origArr = will contain the list of all products.

updatingArr = will be the factory products.

```
  removeDuplicate(origArr: any, updatingArr: any) {
    let ids = new Set(origArr.map((d: { ID: any; }) => d.ID));
    let merged = [...origArr, ...updatingArr.filter((d: { ID: unknown; }) => !ids.has(d.ID))];
  }

ArrayOfProducts.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
   let objectOfFactory = FactoryParent.find((appli: any) => appli.nom === arrayItem.famille.nom);
    console.log(objectOfFactory); // will return the object of the factory array that have the same parent name/name on the product name.
```

At this point I need to add my object inside that array if it's not duplicated
});

Comment: You haven't asked a question about code you've written just listed some requirements. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Comment: @Andy I did an edit, at the moment I don't know if what I'm doing is doable, I'm a bit lost, since yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you...!

```
var FactoryParent = [
        {
            "name": "MT",
            "parent": null,
            "Normes": [
                "NF EN 1111"
            ],
            "version_schema": null
        },
        {
            "name": "MS150",
            "parent": "MR",
            "Normes": [
                "NF EN 7777"
            ],
            "products": [
                {
                    "Id": "78789789784dsz654z",
                    "family": {
                        "name": "MS150",
                        "parent": "MR",
                        "gamme": "RAL X",
                        "serie": "something"
                    }
                }
            ]
    
            },{
                "name": "ME150",
                "parent": "MM",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "Id": "45d456d44567a8a798a79a87456",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "Lunatic S",
                            "serie": "something"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e53e",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "MOMS S",
                            "serie": "somting"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "46f654df564df5645646z",
                        "family": {
                            "name": "ME150",
                            "parent": "MM",
                            "gamme": "RAL S",
                            "serie": "somting"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    
    var  ArrayOfProducts = [
            {
                "Id": "60d4b24fea1adc05a6e4974e",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                    "serie": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "sd798d7s8ds756sd4789",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "DYNAMIC S",
                    "serie": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "46f654df564df5645646z",
                "family": {
                    "name": "ME150",
                    "parent": "MM",
                    "gamme": "RAL S",
                    "serie": "somting"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "88ds456sd4897sd89d7s",
                "family": {
                    "name": "MS150",
                    "parent": "MR",
                    "gamme": "RAL S",
                    "serie": "somting"
                }
            }
        ]

function formatData(){
    return FactoryParent.map(factory => {
        var products = ArrayOfProducts.filter(product =>  factory.name === product.family.name && factory.parent === product.family.parent)
        if(factory?.products){
        products.forEach(product => {
            var isProductExits = factory.products.some(factoryProduct => factoryProduct.Id === product.Id);
            if(!isProductExits){
                factory.products.push(product);
            }
        })
        }
        return factory
        })

}  

console.log(formatData())
```

Comment: thank you for you response I did a tiny mistake the FactoryParent is an Object. It worked with you example tried to reproduce it, it showing me the original array without the addition. Could you help me please ?

Comment: did my code work with FactoryParent array ?